# Infulx db java-api with support of java7

Tags: influxdb

We are going to migrate on infulx db from graphite. Thing is, our application is on Java7 and version 2.8 of infulx db java api supports java 1.8 +.

Can anybody tell me java7 compitable version of infulx db java api ? Please share maven link for the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Influxdb switched to `Java 1.8` from [v2.6](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v25-2016-12-05). You can install any version < 2.6 for Java 7 support.

Here is the github repo for influx-java `v2.5` that supports Java 7,

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/tree/influxdb-java-2.5